# Split Dataframe correctly with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe containing a 'type' column and another 'number' column. The column 'type' is filled with three possible values ​​unique: 'ECU', 'EPMU' and 'PDI'.
Exemple:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Alex", "Quentin", "jean", "Gladis", "Sara", "Xie", "Kevin", "Juan"],
                    "Type": ["ECU", "EMPU", "PBCU", "EMPU", "ECU", "ECU", "ECU", 'ECU'],
                    "number": ["3004", "152", "45", "100", "3001", "3002", "3000", "3054"]
                    })

df1 = df1.set_index('Name')
```

I would like to create two additional data frames: One containing all the 'ECU' lines but not the numbers '3001', '3002', '3003', '3004', '3006'. and another dataframe containing only the 5 numbers that I excluded from the first dataframe created.

I know how to use this command but not how to add a condition to exclude the 5 numbers. Nor how to create a dataframe with the 5 numbers:

```
df = df1[df1['Type'] == 'ECU']
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Can you help us by visually representing the expected output in your question in addition to describing it?

Comment: Yes. I want line 'Juan' and 'Kevin' in the first because 3000 and 3054 is not in the list. and ligne 'Alex', 'Xie' and 'Sara' in the second dataframe because 3004, 3002, and 3001 are in the list. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the first dataframe in this way (`~` is `not`):

```
df1[(df1['Type'] == 'ECU') & (~df1['number'].isin(['3001', '3002', '3003', '3004', '3006']))]
```

Output:

```
   Name    Type number
6   Kevin   ECU 3000
7   Juan    ECU 3054
```

And the second one:

```
df1[df1['number'].isin(['3001', '3002', '3003', '3004', '3006'])]

   Name    Type number
0   Alex    ECU 3004
4   Sara    ECU 3001
5   Xie     ECU 3002
```